# Configuring SQL Anywhere to read from an ASE server

Tags: wcf-ria-services, sap-ase, sqlanywhere, isql

I have a Sybase ASE server that I'm able to connect to with ASE iSql totally fine. The database definition in my sql.ini file looks like:

```
[<NAME>]
master=TCP,<servername>,<port>
```

to connect with iSql, I can make the following command-line call and it works:

```
isql -U <username> -P <password> -S <NAME>
```

My ultimate goal is to use SQL Anywhere's ADO.Net Entity Framework connectivity for a RIA service I'm writing. I'm trying to connect now using SQL Anywhere through Sybase Central (rather than through Visual Studio), and can't get it to work. Under the Identification tab, I use  and  for my credentials and leave the bottom half as "None", under the Database tab, I specify  for the Server name, and under Network I check "TCP/IP", and specify  as the Host, and  as the Port. I get the following error:

```
Fri Nov 20 2009 13:10:10
13:10:10 Attempting to connect using:
UID=sa;ENG=<servername>;CON=SQL_DBC_15c95350;LOG=<log>;LINKS='TCPIP(IP=<servername>;PORT=<port>)'
13:10:10 Attempting to connect to a running server...
13:10:10 Trying to start TCPIP link ...
13:10:10 TCP using Winsock version 2.2
13:10:10 My IP address is 28.230.56.158
13:10:10 My IP address is 127.0.0.1
13:10:10     TCPIP link started successfully
13:10:10 Attempting TCPIP connection (no sasrv.ini cached address)
13:10:10 Looking for server with name <servername>
13:10:10 Trying to find server at address <servername>
13:10:10 Found server, verifying server name
13:10:10 TCP/IP link, function recv(), error code 0
13:10:10 Sending broadcast to find server
13:10:10 Using broadcast address of: 28.230.56.255:<port>
13:10:10 Using broadcast address of: 28.230.56.255:2638
13:10:10 Sending broadcast to find server
13:10:10 Using broadcast address of: 127.255.255.255:<port>
13:10:10 Using broadcast address of: 127.255.255.255:2638
13:10:11 Resending
13:10:12 Resending
13:10:13 Resending
13:10:14 Resending
13:10:15 Resending
13:10:16     Server not found (no reply received)
13:10:16 Failed to connect over TCPIP
13:10:16 Not attempting to autostart server
13:10:16 Cannot connect to server
```

I'm sorry in advance if I left out significant details. I'm new to Sybase, having a strictly Oracle background. If I left out anything you need to know, please post a comment and I'll update the question. Thanks for helping a Sybase newb.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the same ASE server or a SQL Anywhere server? SQL Anywhere (SA) is a database server that is different from ASE. The debug information here shows that Sybase Central is trying to connect to SA, not ASE.

Comment: Is there any way to us SQL Anywhere to connect to ASE? I want to create a .Net RIA service, and SQL Anywhere creates a plugin for Visual Studio's ADO .NET Entity Framework, which would  make things easier for me.

Comment: One thing you can do is define an ASE server as a Remote Server within SQL Anywhere, and create proxy tables within SQL Anywhere which are just forwarded to their equivalent tables in ASE. See here: http://dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1101en/dbusage_en11/aseodbc-odbc-omni-server.html*d5e40031

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do what I was asking (though it could be possible with a proxy table, that's not a desirable solution), so I'm not going to use the .Net RIA Services framework. I'm going to be writing a standard ASP.Net web service.